# Dynamically determine label of current chapter

Tags: cross-referencing

Some pseudo-code to illustrate the problem:

```
\chapter{Another day in paradise}
\label{paradise}
...
\section{The snake appears}
\label{snake}
...
\somemacro % a macro that wants to know the chapter label
```

In the definition of `\somemacro`, is it possible in some way to obtain the string used to `\label` the current chapter (`paradise` in this example)?

Comment: What do you mean by `string`? The name of the chapter like `\nameref` would return? The reference value? The `\@currentlabel` that is set usually with `\refstepcounter` is redefined with each `\refstepcounter` of course

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - sequence of characters. The word is commonly used in other programming languages, but maybe not in TeX/LaTeX. Should I say `token` instead?

Comment: I know what a string is (I've programmed a lot ;-))... Which string do you mean?

Comment: I mean the string `paradise`.

Comment: How should LaTeX know which chapter or section you mean? There's no default way to achieve this

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - I mean the current chapter (should have been clear about that, edited now).

Comment: When do you use `\somemacro`? Do you plan to do any `\refstepcounter` in between?

Comment: @TeXnician - between `\chapter{...}\label{...}` and `\somemacro`, there maybe intervening `\refstepcounter` calls for `\section` and `\subsection`. However, `\somemacro` is specifically interested in the label given to the current chapter, not in those of arbitrary other chapters.

Comment: why do you need a label as opposed to using `\thechapter` which is the current chapter number as would be returned by `\ref{the-label-of-the-chapter}` ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - to hand it over to some external program; not for typesetting.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer: Thanks for unaccepting. I've deleted my answer already -- basically I had the same idea in mind that was posted in the other answer, leaving my answer looking like rubbish, having no chance to use the better idea now. Better to remove it then, this is my fate here.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer - you seem to be very strict with yourself. On the flip side, the comments and answers that you do leave up here are always very good and insightful.

Comment: @MichaelPalmer: Thanks... other's have different views on my answers and posts

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A simple and robust approach is to define a macro that sets the label and remembers the name of the label, e.g.:

```
\newcommand*{\CurrentChapterLabelName}{}
\newcommand*{\ChapterLabel}[1]{%
  \renewcommand*{\CurrentChapterLabelName}{#1}%
  \label{#1}%
}
```

Then, macro `\CurrentChapterLabelName` contains the last label name set by `\ChapterLabel`:

```
\chapter{My chapter title}
\ChapterLabel{MyChapterLabel}

... \section{My section title}\label{MySectionLabel} ...

\SomeMacro can now use \CurrentChapterLabelName;
the latter macro contains 'MyChapterLabel'.
```

Also,
`\chapter` and `\label` could be merged to one macro with parameters for the chapter title, the label name and maybe the shorter title for the table of contents.

This solution works with lots of packages, because internal commands are not hacked.

Comment: Thank you. Your point about compatibility is well taken.